# How to restore health of an hacked router(fritzbox)?

Tags: router, injection

My fritz!box 5530 has been hacked.
I know this because the upload is always very low under 10 mb/s also if my fiber connection would to be 1gb/s|300mb/s.
And when you try router reset to factory settings it simply restart without user/password but with the same rules/settings inside.
Discovering deeply the backup file of the router settings/firmware you find inside a lot of strange rules opening to trojan site and all any any inbound permit everywhere.
Since my ISP doesn't want to verify and change the router I wanna try to clean it/restore his original state in same ways if possible.
Can you help me try to do this if it still possible?
When I try to change parameters inside that router backup file and upload it into the router samething says the file is incorrect.
You can only do this without modifing the file itself.
So I think it's samething that the malware active like protection maybe.
Any solution?

Comment: reflash the firmware

Comment: You could also potentially flash OpenWrt/DD-Wrt on the device if that is supported. Would solve your issue as well.

Comment: I don't know this procedure. I will inspect further